# jQuery "Meet the team" effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, onmouseover

I'm trying to create a jQuery effect for [this block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41qW0.jpg).
The idea is, that on mouseover the other photos are "looking" at the selected one. Here is the html code.

```
<ul class="team">
    <li><img src="pics/team/t-0001.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="pics/team/t-0002.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="pics/team/t-0003.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Theoretically I understand, that when the mouse is over one of these li elements, I have to change the src value of images in the others. And there are several arrays needed where these paths can be stored.

But in practice I have big problems.

What should I do first? May be there are some examples or plugins?

I will appreciate any help.

---

Thank you for help! Sorry, could not answer earlier, had a lot of work to do.

I have found a solution. It is very simple and not so flexible, but it works. I'm using background images.

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/KSYUC/4/

Comment: For starters you could see that site's implementation of it.. View Source.

Comment: @KseniaMurach edit my post with an sample to get u started

Comment: Should they follow the mouse or look to a "hover-selected" image (what happens when the mouse is between two images)? Can you show us the CSS that generates the grid out of the list (do the cells have a fixed ratio)?

Comment: They do not follow the mouse, just looking at the "hover-selected" image.
Nothing happens when the mouse is between two images.
All list elements have fixed width and fixed height.

Comment: @KseniaMurach updated with a working sample and fiddle

Comment: These answers skip over the most important part of this problem. Sure you may know how to swap two images now, but which images do you swap!? You also need more than 2 images per face so it can look in any direction. I think you'd need a 2d array for the people and then find adjacent elements to the one hovered over and change their image accordingly. But even that only covers adjacent faces only, what about people one space away?

Comment: Right, that's what I'm trying to explain with my image below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could simplify the problem, by not having 9 images of each person, is to actually work with one composite image per person, with all possibilities.
Maybe something like this (the arrow shows the direction in which the person should be looking) in one single image:

[image: Face direction]

This lets you alter the direction just by changing the background position (using the regular intervals that are determined by your image size) of the image through CSS.
It also has the benefit that all possibilities for a face are loaded at the same time, and not when the face changes (which may cause the image to flicker or require preloading).

Then you'd have to calculate which image to use for each face, depending its relative location to the selected one.
It's a matter of arithmetic comparison between coordinates.

So if you iterate all faces against the selected one, then if the current's Y is higher than the selected Y, then it'll be one of the top three "sub-images", and then you'd compare X to see if it is less, equal, or greater, to determine which one of the three.
The same applies to all three rows of possible faces.
Ultimately it boils down to comparing both Y and X for less, equal, or greater. That way you'd calculate the offset for both X and Y in the background position.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img.smart').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('background-position':'-150px 0');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css('background-position':'0 0');
  },
);
```

Put one "double" image with display block, width and height of normal image and change the css position to negative and back.
Note: I've added to each image the class="smart" for easier jQuery selection

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would recommend you using json instead of regular arrays... Why? well you can assign given json object a username that then contains all the images for that user and the same thing for the rest of the users and then just loop through that users json object on mouse over.
say you have an object like so

```
 myvalues = [{"userone":['srcone','srctwo'],"usertwo":['srcone','srctwo']}]
```

the u iterate it like so

```
for (var key in myvalues) {
    var obj = myvalues[key];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        alert("User:"+prop+" Valueone: "+obj[prop][0]+" Valuetwo:"+obj[prop][1]);
   }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xRuBR/2/